# Display message if close window in ASP.NET but not on PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I would like to display a message to the user only if they close my ASP.NET Web Forms page or navigate away from it. If they click any Button, LinkButton, AutoPostBack element, or anything else that will postback then I don't want to show the message.

So far I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var postback = false;

addToPostBack = function(func) {
    var old__doPostBack = __doPostBack;
    if (typeof __doPostBack != "function") {
        __doPostBack = func;
    } else {
        __doPostBack = function(t, a) {
            if (func(t, a)) old__doPostBack(t, a);
        }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    addToPostBack(function(t,a) {
        postback = true;
    });
});

$(window).bind("beforeunload", function() {
    if (!postback) {
        return "message";
    }
});
</script>
```

This works partially but seems to stop AutoPostBack events from firing and still shows the message for LinkButtons etc.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can check for your answer here http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/demos/OnBeforeUnloadDemo1.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will take a timestamp of when __doPostBack was called and then carry out the default behavior.

The onbeforeunload event will only show your custom message when the difference between it's timestamp and the latest __doPostBack timestamp is greater than allowedWaitTime.

Usage: include it anywhere in your page.

## Update:

This will now handle WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions also

```
(function ($) {

    if (typeof $ !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('jQuery required');
    }

    /* The time in milliseconds to allow between a __doPostBack call and 
       showing the onbeforeunload message. */
    var allowedWaitTime = 100,

        timeStamp = new Date().getTime(),

        // Each function to override
        baseFuncs = {
            __doPostBack: this.__doPostBack,
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions: this.WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions
        };

    // Set timeStamp when each baseFunc is called
    for (var baseFunc in baseFuncs) {
        (function (func) {
            this[func] = function () {
                var baseFunc = baseFuncs[func];
                timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
                if (typeof baseFunc === 'function') {
                    baseFunc.apply(arguments.callee, arguments);
                }
            }
        })(baseFunc);
    }

    /* Form submit buttons don't call __doPostBack so we'll set timeStamp 
       manually on click. */
    $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
        timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
    });

    $(this).on('beforeunload', function (e) {

        // Only return string if allowedWaitTime has elapsed
        if (e.timeStamp - timeStamp > allowedWaitTime) {
            return 'message';
        }
    });
}).call(window, jQuery);
```

Comment: This seems to be the best solution. Thank you very much. I increased the allowedWaitTime to 100 as I found that a normal submit usually took 45ms.

Comment: I also found this didn't work with buttons that called WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions instead of __doPostBack, so I copied the code to override __doPostBack for WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions.

Comment: I've added support for WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions so timeStamp will be set for both methods.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this out:-

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on("click", function () {
        window.onbeforeunload = null;
    });

});

window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    return "message";
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get that to work (would always show the message). BY binding to click wouldn't that mean even if you clicked an empty part of the screen it would cancel the onbeforeunload event?

Comment: So if you click inside the browser, it will make the `onbeforeunload` as null for that click and if you try to naivgate through to some other Url it will show the message.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var isChanged = false;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').click(function () {
                isChanged = true;
            });
            $('select').click(function () {
                isChanged = true; 
            });
        });

        $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
            if (isChanged) {
                return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';                
                }           
        })

    </script>
```

This works when user clicks on any `input`(button) or `select`(dropdownlist) in the form.

Full code goes here :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isChanged = false;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').click(function () {
                isChanged = true;                

            });
            $('select').click(function () {
                isChanged = true;                

            });
        });

        $(window).bind("beforeunload", function () {
            if (isChanged) {
                return '>>>>>Before You Go<<<<<<<< \n Your custom message go here';                
                }           
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox" />      
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button Text="button" runat="server" ID="btn" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddl">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="One" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Two" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox Text="Check" runat="server" ID="chk" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="radio">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="One" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Two" />
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this handles LinkButtons (rendered as A tag), is that right? Also if you click an input or select then click cancel to abort leaving the page, it won't ask you a second time.

Answer (score 0):

on your link-buttons and buttons set `onclick="$(window).unbind("beforeunload");return true;"`

your autopostback elements should set the `onchange` or what ever causes the autopostback set to `onchange="$(window).unbind("beforeunload");return true;"`

be sure to bind the beforeunload again after the postback happened!

Comment: Would also have to rebind the beforeunload if the user presses cancel on the alert box.